# Succinct data structure to return occurences of letters until an index

Tags: data-structures, succinct-data-structures

I want to try and use a succinct type data structure in order to find the amount of occurences of a letter $C$ in a string $S$ until a given index $I$.

Assume we have a string $S$ of length $n$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$. I want to build a data structure whose space usage is at most $O(n)$ machine-size words.

Given $C$ (a valid letter from $\Sigma$) and an index $i$ such that $0 \le i \lt n$, the data structure should be able to return the number of occurrences of $C$ in $S[1..i]$ as efficiently as possible (but not necessarily in $O(1)$ time). This is the only query possible.

The data structure is aware of $S$ when created.

What I've tried to far is to split the string $S$ into blocks and to store info about each block with the number of occurrences of each letter in the  previous block. I couldn't find how to make it lighter so the memory complexity be as requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put it another way, you want to implement rank queries on an arbitrary string with an arbitrary alphabet.

If $n$ is of modest size, the usual approach is to use a [Wavelet tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_Tree), associating a succinct binary rank index with each node in the tree. The shape of the tree is arbitrary, but using a Huffman tree gives you a data structure that is very close to zero-order entropy compression.

When the alphabet is very large, though, the size and implementation of the tree itself becomes a concern. A way to fix this which seems to work well in practice is to store $\left\lceil \log_2 n \right\rceil$ rank-select indexes of length $|S|$, but use an index implementation that it sensitive to local variation in density, such as [esp](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0610001v1.pdf) or [RRR](http://alexbowe.com/rrr/).

This is covered in Claude & Navarro's 2008 paper, [*Practical Rank/Select Queries over Arbitrary Sequences*](http://personales.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/ps/spire08.1.pdf). There may be some more recent work than this if you chase citations, but that's a good start.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try a few special cases:

- If the letters in the string are all distinct, then a permuted index would give $O(1)$ lookup with $n$ words of storage.

  - Data: an array $A$ where $A[c]$ is the position of the letter $c$ in the string.
  - Data size: Array of size $n$.
  - Query: $Q(C,I) = 1$ if $A[C] \le I$ and $Q(C,I) = 0$ otherwise.
  - Query time: $O(1)$
- If the string only contains $O(1)$ distinct letters, then you could store the set of positions of each letter independently.

  - Data: for each letter $C$, a binary search tree of the positions of $C$ in $S$, where each node stores the weight of the subtree.
  - Data size: a forest of trees with a total of $n$ nodes.
  - Query: $Q(C,I)$ is the sum of the weights of the subtree to the left of $I$ in the positions tree for the letter $C$.
  - Query time: $O(\lg(n))$ (binary tree lookup)

That last data structure does in fact generalize to the case where the string can contain an arbitrary arrangement of letters. There are now $n$ trees, each of which could have a size up to $n$, but the total size of the forest is still only $n$, so the storage requirement is $\Theta(n)$. The query time is $O(\lg(n))$. The time it takes to set up the data structure is $O(n \lg^k(n))$ for some $k$ that I can't be bothered to calculate.

Comment: hi, thats for replying. as it seems, people said that there is efficient way to get the number of occurences than Lg(n). the main problem is when the string contains unknown number of occurences of each letter and thats what Im trying to solve.